# Trying to get property of non-object - private message laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Welcome ! I have a problem I try to use this https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger Laravel package for private messaging on Laravel 5.2. When i didn't have any recipients I could post a message but when I add new user to database and recipients showed in form now I have an error : trying to get property of non -object. All controllers and views are copied from examples from link above.

Regards

Comment: Can you show us the code you used and the database structure of your application? We can't guess what the problem is.

Comment: Post us your code and error so we can comment on it

Answer (score 0):

Message controller :

```
    <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Models\Message;
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Models\Participant;
use Cmgmyr\Messenger\Models\Thread;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Show all of the message threads to the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function index()
{
    $currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;

    // All threads, ignore deleted/archived participants
    $threads = Thread::getAllLatest()->get();

    // All threads that user is participating in
    // $threads = Thread::forUser($currentUserId)->latest('updated_at')->get();

    // All threads that user is participating in, with new messages
    // $threads = Thread::forUserWithNewMessages($currentUserId)->latest('updated_at')->get();

    return view('messenger.index', compact('threads', 'currentUserId'));
}

/**
 * Shows a message thread.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function show($id)
{
    try {
        $thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        Session::flash('error_message', 'The thread with ID: ' . $id . ' was not found.');

        return redirect('messages');
    }

    // show current user in list if not a current participant
    // $users = User::whereNotIn('id', $thread->participantsUserIds())->get();

    // don't show the current user in list
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $users = User::whereNotIn('id', $thread->participantsUserIds($userId))->get();

    $thread->markAsRead($userId);

    return view('messenger.show', compact('thread', 'users'));
}

/**
 * Creates a new message thread.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function create()
{
    $users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

    return view('messenger.create', compact('users'));
}

/**
 * Stores a new message thread.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $thread = Thread::create(
        [
            'subject' => $input['subject'],
        ]
    );

    // Message
    Message::create(
        [
            'thread_id' => $thread->id,
            'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
            'body'      => $input['message'],
        ]
    );

    // Sender
    Participant::create(
        [
            'thread_id' => $thread->id,
            'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
            'last_read' => new Carbon,
        ]
    );

    // Recipients
    if (Input::has('recipients')) {
        $thread->addParticipant($input['recipients']);
    }

    return redirect('messages');
}

/**
 * Adds a new message to a current thread.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function update($id)
{
    try {
        $thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        Session::flash('error_message', 'The thread with ID: ' . $id . ' was not found.');

        return redirect('messages');
    }

    $thread->activateAllParticipants();

    // Message
    Message::create(
        [
            'thread_id' => $thread->id,
            'user_id'   => Auth::id(),
            'body'      => Input::get('message'),
        ]
    );

    // Add replier as a participant
    $participant = Participant::firstOrCreate(
        [
            'thread_id' => $thread->id,
            'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
        ]
    );
    $participant->last_read = new Carbon;
    $participant->save();

    // Recipients
    if (Input::has('recipients')) {
        $thread->addParticipant(Input::get('recipients'));
    }

    return redirect('messages/' . $id);
}
```

}

Standard routes:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'messages'], function () {
 Route::get('/', ['as' => 'messages', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@index']);
Route::get('/create', ['as' => 'messenger.create', 'uses' =>    'MessagesController@create']);
Route::post('/', ['as' => 'messages.store', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@store']);
Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.show', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@show']);
Route::put('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.update', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@update']);
});
```

And standard view:

```
   {!! Form::open(['route' => 'messages.store']) !!}
   <div class="col-md-6">
  <!-- Subject Form Input -->
  <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('subject', 'Subject', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
      {!! Form::text('subject', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>

  <!-- Message Form Input -->
  <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('message', 'Message', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
      {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>

  @if($users->count() > 0)
  <div class="checkbox">
      @foreach($users as $user)
          <label title="{{ $user->name }}"><input type="checkbox" name="recipients[]" value="{{ $user->id }}">{!!$user->name!!}</label>
      @endforeach
  </div>
  @endif

  <!-- Submit Form Input -->
  <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
  </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
     </div>
```